# Why my IF isn't working properly?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I'm coding a function to get the "data-screen" attribute of a clicked element (if there's any to get) and take some action based on whether the currently active screen is same as or different from that of the clicked element.

The problem is my If check for undefined works alright but ignores the second condition:

- If I click elsewhere on the page: nothing. :D
- If I click on the Home link: nothing. :D
- If I click on the New Quest: it writes on console.  :(

Thanks for any help! Here is my code:

HTML

```
<li><a data-screen="home" href="#">Home</a></li>
<li><a data-screen="new-quest" href="#">New Quest</a></li>

<div id="container" data-screen="new-quest"></div>
```

JAVACSCRIPT

```
function getScreen(){
    var body = $('body'),
        activeScreen = $('#content').attr('data-screen'),
        screen;
    body.on('tap',function(e){
        screen = $(e.target).attr('data-screen');
        if(screen != undefined && screen != activeScreen){
            console.log('Target <data-screen>: ' + screen);
            console.log('Active Screen: ' + activeScreen);
        }
     });
}
```

The condition is supposed to be like this:

`screen` get the `data-screen` value for the clicked element.
FIRST CONDITION:
If `screen` is `undefined`, cause the element doesn't have the attribute the stop or else keep going.
SECOND CONDITION:
If the first check is OK, it has some "screen" on it, check if the `screen` is DIFERENT from the `activeScreen` which is an attribute for the page container.

Because if they DIFERENT I can render another content for the page. But they are EQUALS and it keeps writing on console, even when it should stop.

Comment: activeScreen  is out of scope. Put is as global.

Comment: You can't compare two jQuery objects, even if they contain the same element. For example, `$( 'body' ) != $( 'body' )`.

Comment: @opalenzuela No it isn't.

Comment: @opalenzuela and "put it as a global" is almost never the right answer.

Comment: @Juhana I don't see any jQuery objects being compared.  However the OP is (confusingly) using `$` notation on non-jQuery objects.

Comment: FYI you don't need to prefix all your variables with `$`.

Comment: @EvanTrimboli perhaps he's a recovering PHP programmer? ;-)

Comment: The code is wrong, for obvious reasons. I was just suggesting more tests to perform. Or at least, a fiddle.

Comment: And use the `jquery.data()` instead of `jquery.attr('data-xxxx')`.

Comment: Oops, the `$`-variables were a bit misleading.

Comment: @opalenzuela what obvious reasons are those, then?  Apart from a couple of oddities (none of which should actually break the code) I don't see anything, and certainly not a scope problem with `activeScreen`.

Comment: Who is calling the getScreen() method? Also, I don't understand your third use case. If somebody clicks on New Quest and if that is not the current screen, the statements will get logged to the console. What is wrong with that? I hope that you do realize that $activescreen is set only once when the getScreen() method is called and is never updated on any other tap.

Comment: @Chandranshu that's what I was wondering too - the OP hasn't shown what the value of `data-screen` is for `#content`.  If it's `home` then the code appears to be working as desired.

Comment: I've changed the $ variables, xD sorry!!

@Alnitak, when i've changed the attr for data, the code stoped working.

getScreen() is on the $(document).ready()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, your code (apart from a typo) is working as intended, as proven in this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/LgMYd/

Change `<div id="content" data-screen="home">` to `<div id="content" data-screen="new-quest">` to test the other case.

Edit: I did fix the typo that's mentioned in the answer above, but I think that was just a typo you made when removing all the $'s.

Also, as said in the comments, the active screen will only be determined ONCE on document ready. IF you are creating a single page application, this will not work the way you expect it to! In that case, you would have to update the active screen variable each time a new view is loaded.

Answer (score -1):

Typo in your variable? A stray $ perhaps?

```
screen != undefined && $screen != activeScreen
```

to become

```
screen != undefined && screen != activeScreen
```

Comment: The OP's original code had `$` signs everywhere - the one remaining one here is likely a typo just in the question and not in the live code.

Comment: Was there a reason for this downvote? My answer directly addresses OP's question `Why my IF isn't working properly?`